# 404 Image Nominations

Tags: feature-request, design

According to the [Top 7](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), we need to select a 404 image -  an image that will be displayed when users try to bring up a page that [does not exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/404).

Please quote the source so the team can negotiate rights if necessary.

Comment: My comment applies to nearly all the answers below: The 404 image chosen should not be completely confusing to beginners.  (The Tux one is pretty funny and not confusing; the "kernel panic" text ideas would be confusing and potentially worrying.)

Answer (score 12):

we could create a black image showing the error message in kernelpanic-flavor.

like http://orionida.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/kernel-panic.jpg but with some other data and errors (404 should be shown somewhere)

Comment: Save on bandwidth... we could just do this in html... and it'd still be funny

Comment: let's put some html5 non compatible with ie8/7/6 and some SVG so we can lough at windowsians who still uses XP.
Mouhahahahahahahaha

Comment: Oh the irony -- your suggested image link is returning a 404.

Answer (score 11):

It's not complete(as in, 25 rows of text) but maybe this is a start?

```
 [<c0292932>] __get_page+0xe2/0x1d2
 [<c0120423>] search_disk+0xe9/0x19d
 [<c09283d2>] search_backup_disk+0xf1/0x21
 [<c0e29fa1>] search_frantically+0x12/0xe12
 [<c0021df0>] __wait_on_server_magic+0x48/0x9
Warning: server_magic timeout reached!
 [<c0f2359d>] get_error_page+0x2/0xd34
 [<c0d34a9d>] __alert_code_monkeys+0x03/0xe9d
Warning: code_monkeys not responding to messages
 [<c0a92d92>] __render_error_page+0x0/0x404
 [<c02a94da>] render_404_error_page+0x0/0x0
Server panic - Aiee, your file was not found!
```

I made it community wiki, so edit this to be more complete, then just put it on your favorite terminal and screen shot it (or if you want to be really awesome, recompile linux and put in these functions and make the linux kernel actually say this, and then screen shot it)

Comment: Hmmm... a great idea for sure... I'm not very good at writing kernel modules, though.

Answer (score 10):

## We couldn't find the page you were looking for...

Looks like Tux tried the <kbd>rm -rf /</kbd> command again. We really need to take that computer away from him.

[image: Tux gets carried away.]

Source: [linux.org.uk](ftp://ftp.linux.org.uk/pub/linux/).

Comment: Too much Linux, not enough Unix.

Comment: @gvkv: Look closer at the picture... there's Unix stuff there :)

Comment: Too much Pepsi, not enough Coke.

Answer (score 5):

Xeno [found an image](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/image-we-should-use-for-something) that I think could be a decent 404 picture, although we probably need to add text somewhere:

[image: Proposed 404 image]

We've got a couple other versions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qqOn.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVOQS.png)

Comment: I like the version here: http://i.imgur.com/uVOQS.png I think it makes no sense to include the java mascot Duke here ;-)

Comment: @echox Yeah, I like that one the most too, although the editing was rather poor and should probably be redone if we actually use this for something

Answer (score 3):

```
cat: /foo/bar: No such file or directory
```

Maybe not cat, but how about GET:

```
HTTP GET: http://unix.stackexchange.com/foo/bar: No such file or directory
```

(Does it really have to be an image?)

Answer (score 3):

[image: useless use of cat]

(from [GirlieMac](http://www.flickr.com/photos/girliemac/)'s [HTTP Status Cats](http://www.flickr.com/photos/girliemac/sets/72157628409467125/))

Answer (score 0):

How about this as a U&L 404 "image" ? I tried to simulate loading (mounting) a URL, then a have a generalized `fsck` error message related to failing to find a URL.

```
# mount /http/URL /dev/console
mount: special device /http/URL does not exist
# fsck /http/url
fsck 1.43.1 (29-Jun-2016)
fsck: No such file or directory while trying to open /http/url

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct
URL. If the device is valid and it really contains a URL (and
not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is 
corrupt, and you might try running fsck with an alternate superblock.

You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
#
```