# image we should use for something...

Tags: discussion

I dunno what we should use this for or if it should be *remixed*. But I found this and I think it'd be good for us. [image: from left: BSD Daemon Beastie, Java's Duke, OpenBSD's Puffy, Darwin's Hexley, Linux's Tux, GNU's Gnu]

Does anyone know what the second one from the left is?

**Question is:** what should we use it for?

---

For ease of reference, the depicted mascots are: [Beastie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_Daemon) (BSD), [Duke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_(mascot)#Mascot) (Java), [Hexley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexley#Mascot) (Darwin), [Puffy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD) (OpenBSD), [Tux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux) (Linux), and a [gnu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU#GNU_logo) (GNU)

Comment: The guy second from the left is the Java mascot apparently.

Comment: I like it except for Duke; I have no idea what he's doing in this picture

Comment: *One of these things is not like the others, One of these things just doesn't belong, Can you tell which thing is not like the others By the time I finish my song?*

Comment: @Michael could probably get someone to remove Duke, if no one volunteers and we have an idea what we'd use it for... I'm sure I can get a friend to do it.

Comment: Someone should make a cartoon with blender using these characters... I'd watch it :P, hell I'd pay for it.

Comment: Here's an [edited version](http://i.imgur.com/3qqOn.png). I moved Puffy left, but we could also [move Beastie right](http://i.imgur.com/uVOQS.png) to fill the space

Comment: @Michael that's great... now if only we could come up with something to use it for

Comment: @xeno I think this could be turned into a decent [404 image](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120/404-image-nominations)

Comment: @Michael maybe you should submit it to that ;)

Answer (score 3):

If someone wanted to create a similar graphic here are some sources for the images

- [Golden Gnu meditating](http://www.gnu.org/graphics/meditate.html) (also the Golden Gnu [listening to a CD](http://www.gnu.org/graphics/listen.html))
- [Tux the Linux Penguin](http://www.isc.tamu.edu/~lewing/linux/)
- [Beastie the BSD Daemon](http://www.freebsd.org/copyright/daemon.html) (also this [reasonably good version](http://www.digitaldaemon.com/Image/Large/standing_daemon.jpg) of Beastie)
- [Hexley the Darwin Platypus](http://www.hexley.com/)
- [Puffy the OpenBSD Fish](http://openbsd.org/art4.html) (the version above is "Cartoon Puffy")

Another similar sort of character:

- [SUSE Samurai](http://www.novell.com/company/logo/img/viral_samurai.png) (other versions available on the [Novell Logo page](http://www.novell.com/company/logo/))

Comment: Isn't the daemon the mascot for all three BSDs? Then Puffy wold be superfluous I think. I mean, otherwise we had to include Fedora hat, Ubuntu logo, Suse gecko and Debian shell too. (And still Gentoo and Linux mint and Mandrake would protest...)

Comment: I think the focus was to involve the "characters" associated with Unix and Linux in the design of this site, rather than to be perfectly representative.

Comment: Thanks moberlerly, great resource. +1 ( That lizzard does not look like a samurai at all, more like a mongrol )

Comment: Hmm. What kind of CDs can the Golden GNU, in good conscience, listen to?