# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi All,

Unix and Linux site has been officially launched!. Thank you for your [design feedback](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/design-ideas-for-unix-and-linux-site-updated) and congrats!

I ended up taking the mascots off the header. I agree with you that they made the site a bit childish, also it's hard to cover all the different OSes.

If you have see any css/styling issues, please start a new question tagged with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) I'll try to fix them asap!

Again, congrats and thank you!

Comment: I love it, simple, elegant, you've done well @Jin. My heartfelt thanks.

Comment: Not bad! Almost as good as the AU site layout :P

Comment: I **really** like the fonts!

Comment: Great job! Really like that it is not "overstyled".

Comment: After some time not visiting the site (busy in new job) I just saw the new design and I, too, really like it. Well done!

Comment: I like this design.  It's really classy and dignified.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's too late but I just wanted to say a big **THANK YOU**! Jin, you put a lot of effort in your work, you listened to our feedback and you took it into account. You did some very nice work here and elsewhere on Stack Exchange. Thank you!