# What happened to the appearance of tags?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, design

Just now I have a look at the [tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags) page and see that they all have a slash just like the things on title bar. That looks somewhat weird to me regarding that they are not at the root directory. For example `/questions` has a slash because it's at the top level directory, but `/bash` is not OK because it should have been `/tags/bash` (`/bash` would yield "No such file or directory").

This reminds me of the second [design draft](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/337/250) where the tag is surrounded by square brackets `[bash]` and has a monospace font. It was my suggestion and I liked that, but anything else can be better than a slash :)

Comment: anyone else think meta looks nicer than our parent?

Comment: The square brackets in the draft design definitely looked better; I'm not sure if there was a reason it was changed

Comment: @Jeff I think I could do with a little explanation to that `status-bydesign` tag. Like when you say no to a kid you also tell them something. What you say probably doesn't make much sense and the kid is probably still sad, but it's better than just "No".

Answer (score 10):

While the leading slash works for the banner as a cute play on convention, it fails for tags.  I understood it was a bit of design, but, even with some experience on Stack Overflow, it was confusing at first.

I foresee more confusion when people start talking about "/tag"; that is, including the slash as part of the tag name.  The way it's presented, it also seems that's how you should be searching for tags by name, and so forth.

Something else would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

I like the current tag design more than either of the draft.

I think that combined with the headings such as /question they bring in the right amount of unix-ness into the design even if they aren't 100% correct under some particular mapping of UI elements to a real file system.

Answer (score 3):

I do agree that the `/` is too confusing. If square-brackets use one too many characters, then I suggest using either:

- `#my-tag`
- `~my-tag`
- `$my-tag`

I know using the hash is what twitter does, but for this SE, I think it fits and looks a little bit terminal-esque.

I think I prefer the `$` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think not having `/tag` in front of each tag makes sense from a *design* point of view because it wouldn't add any useful information considering you already know it's a tag.

I agree you would be right from a computing point of view, but I'm better off with the first option.

Of course, having such `/tags` may be a little confusing with code or command-line examples.

Comment: I'm *not* suggesting that we should put a "/tags" prefix in there. I mean we should replace that "/" with something else.

Comment: Well, let's say I replied to the *"`/bash` [...] should have been `/tags/bash`"* part.  Glad to hear you neither find this a better solution ;-)