# Should this site get a new look?

Tags: discussion, design

The look of this site has been designed with commandlines in mind. However, in most modern Linux distro's you don't even need to use them.
But on the other side, many people here use the commandline.

What do you think? Should the site get a new look that's not too much inspired by commandlines?

*By the way, I like [those mascots](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/337/33094). I think they will look good.*

Comment: I'm curious as to what visual elements correspond to, or are inspired by, the command line? It is not evident to me.

Comment: Prefixing stuff with `/` and font

Comment: Fair enough. I'd never really thought of it that way...

Comment: I thought most file managers displayed their current working directories. `/...` isn't associated with the shell; it's associated with the filesystem.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any direct correlation between the visual design of the site and the command line.

I think the site designers have done a good job within the brand family of both keeping the interface clean and uncluttered, while differentiating it sufficiently from the other Stack Exchange sites.

With the implementation of recent [community requested changes](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/are-requests-for-changes-to-the-site-design-ignored-by-default), I feel the overall design of the site is about right.

That's not to say that there is no room for improvement, incremental or otherwise. A site's design should evolve and your question is perfectly valid.

So don't be discouraged from participating here by the downvotes. It seems that your call for a complete redesign, however, meant that rather than answer, most of us just indicated a contra view with a downvote.

As to your point about not needing to use the command line in modern distros, that may be technically true; many people do manage to use *nix distros without opening a terminal. But that is like buying an ice cream and just eating the cone—for *nix enthusiasts, the good stuff is on the inside.